# force kill a buffer?

Tags: buffers, kill-buffer

I have a buffer (belonging to ein mode that got into a bad state) that throws an elisp error every time I try to kill it (using ibuffer, `M-x kill-this-buffer`, etc.)

Backtrace suggests that the buffer is trying to run some elisp that is failing. Is it possible to just kill that buffer without running any hooks?

Comment: maybe you can try to set kill-buffer-hook, which is buffer-local to nil. Don't know if this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to write a tiny bit of Lisp. Type the following into `M-:` (`M-x eval-expression`). You don't need line breaks, they're just for readability.

```
(with-current-buffer "name of buffer"
  (let (kill-buffer-hook kill-buffer-query-functions)
    (kill-buffer)))
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work in my case: `ein:notebook-kill-buffer-query` hook runs and causes an error down the road.

Comment: @LeoAlekseyev I think I see the problem: the hooks are local, and `kill-buffer` implicitly switches to the buffer that it's about to be killed. My new version should work.